# How to avoid duplicating data fetching logic in Next.js App Routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a project using Next.js 13's new App Routes feature and I'm wondering how I can avoid duplicating data fetching logic between my **metadata** generation function and my **page component**.

/[slug]/page.tsx

```
export async function generateMetadata(params: { slug: string }) {
  const slug = params.slug;
  const data = await getProducts(params.slug);
  return {
    title: data.title,
    //...
  };
}

export async function Page(params: { slug: string }) {
  const slug = params.slug;
  const data = await getProducts(params.slug);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

As you can see, both functions are fetching the data using the getProducts function. I want to avoid duplicating this logic and fetch the data only once.

Is there a way to fetch the data once and pass it as props to both functions?

Comment: Just in-line it: `const data = await getProducts(params.slug);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `fetch` api inside `getProducts` it will be already handled by `next.js`. if you do not use `fetch`, use [React cache().](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching#react-cache)

[from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata)

> When rendering a route, Next.js will automatically deduplicate fetch
> requests for the same data across generateMetadata,
> generateStaticParams, Layouts, Pages, and Server Components. React
> cache can be used if fetch is unavailable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, I am not using fetch. An error happened ["getProducts" is not a valid Page export field] after I use cache.

Comment: did you export  `export const getProducts = cache(async (slug: string) => {}`

Comment: I created the cache function in page.tsx and it causes the error. Finally, I open a new file and no error was found. Thanks.